# Assume hibernation file 'hiberfil.sys' is always on the boot volume?

Tags: windows, power-management, hibernate

Is is safe to assume that the `hiberfil.sys` is always located on the boot volume i.e. `%SYSTEMDRIVE%`?
Or can it be relocated to another volume, or disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what this thread, ["Move hibernate file to a different drive"](https://serverfault.com/questions/34017/move-hibernate-file-to-a-different-drive), says:

> You can't relocate the HIBERFIL.SYS
>   file to any partition other than the
>   boot partition. This is because it's
>   needed very early in to boot process
>   to resume from hiberation and the boot
>   loader (NTLDR) code, needing to be
>   compact and optimized, doesn't have
>   the ability to load the HIBERFIL.SYS
>   from an arbitrary location.

Answer (score 0):

It must be located always on the same drive where Windows reside, ala %systemdrive% (which is not necessary the boot volume).

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of or seen a way to move it and I've looked.  It's always on the %systemdrive%.